# Alternate two values

Tags: stream, scheme, racket, lazy-sequences

I have the code

```
(define alternate
(letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons x (lambda () (f (+ x 1)))))])
(lambda () (f 1))))
```

The result is 1,2,3..
How i could change it to take 1,2,1,2,1,2..

I tried cons inside the f but didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this homework or exam work?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it as a small modification of your existing code:

```
(define alternate
  (letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons x (lambda () (f (if (= x 1) 2 1)))))])
    (lambda () (f 1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward to implement using [streams](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html):

```
(define (alternate)
  (stream-map (lambda (x)
                (if (even? x) 1 2))
              (in-naturals)))
```

The trick here is that a stream is built using [stream-cons](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-cons%29%29), which basically does what you're implementing by hand: it creates a list where its elements are "promises" that get evaluated only when needed.

> `stream-cons` produces a lazy stream for which stream-first forces the evaluation of first-expr to produce the first element of the stream, and stream-rest forces the evaluation of rest-expr to produce a stream for the rest of the returned stream.

This shows how `alternate` returns an infinite stream of elements of the form `1 2 1 2 1 2 ...`

```
(define alt (alternate))

(stream-ref alt 0)
=> 1
(stream-ref alt 1)
=> 2
(stream-ref alt 2)
=> 1
(stream-ref alt 3)
=> 2
```

Alternatively, if you need a list of *n* elements of the sequence use this procedure, which by the way should be part of Racket in the first place:

```
(define (stream-take s n)
  (if (zero? n)
      '()
      (cons (stream-first s)
            (stream-take (stream-rest s) (sub1 n)))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(define alt (alternate))

(stream-take alt 0)
=> '()
(stream-take alt 1)
=> '(1)
(stream-take alt 2)
=> '(1 2)
(stream-take alt 3)
=> '(1 2 1)
```

Comment: I use a function to call the stream n times.If i call it once i want '(1).2nd: '(1 2) 3rd time: '(1 2 1) 4th time: '(1 2 1 2).This stream doesn't work this way..:(

Comment: @Rea it's quite possible to get that result with my implementation, see my updated answer for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You might also find generators useful: [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Generators.html?q=generator#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/generator..rkt%29._generator%29%29)

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.3.5 [3m].
Language: racket [custom].
> (require racket/generator)
> (define g (generator () (let LOOP () (yield 1) (yield 2) (LOOP))))
> (g)
1
> (g)
2
> (g)
1
> (g)
2
```

UPDATE:

Even better, use an infinite-generator:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.3.5 [3m].
Language: racket [custom].
> (require racket/generator)
> (define g (infinite-generator (yield 1) (yield 2)))
> (g)
1
> (g)
2
> (g)
1
> (g)
2
```